# How to use Google API to get images from internet and to insert the first result in an UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a UITableView with products and each product have an UIImageView which should be populated from google using google API.
So if my product name is "iPhone X" then my UIImageView should be populated with the first image result from google which will be an image with an iPhone X.
Sometimes is getting me the image for the first product and also all products from UITableView will have the same image, but 90% of time is getting me the Default Image which is a image with a dog.

Here is my code:

```
    class ProductsViewController: UIViewController{

        var query: String?
        var googlePhotosArray = [Item]()
        var productsArray = [Product]()



        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated)

            fetchPhotosForProductsFromGoogle()
        }


        // Download photos from Google for products avatar
        func fetchPhotosForProductsFromGoogle(){

            for eachProduct in productsArray{

                let productNameWithSpaces = eachProduct.name!
                query = productNameWithSpaces.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_", options: .literal, range: nil)
            }
            guard let requestURL = URL(string: URLGoogle.googleAPIUrl + "\(query ?? "ChihuahuaExtreme")" + URLGoogle.googleSearchPhotosOnly + URLGoogle.googleSearchEngineID + URLGoogle.googleAPIKey)
                else { fatalError(Constants.urlNotFound) }
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: requestURL) { (data, response, error) in

                guard error == nil else {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async { SCLAlertView().showError(Constants.error, subTitle: Constants.errorURLSesion) }
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let googlePhotosList = try JSONDecoder().decode(GoogleSearchModel.self, from: data!)

                    self.googlePhotosArray = self.googlePhotosArray + googlePhotosList.items
                } catch { }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.productsTableView.reloadData()
                }
                }.resume()
        }

    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = productsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.identifierProductCell, for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
        cell.delegate = self

        cell.productTitleLabel.text = productsArray[indexPath.row].name!
        cell.productDescriptionLabel.text = productsArray[indexPath.row].prodDescription!
        cell.productPriceLabel.text = String(format: Constants.floatTwoDecimals, productsArray[indexPath.row].price) + Constants.currencyPound

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let productPhotoURL = self.googlePhotosArray.first?.link ?? Constants.defaultProductPhotoURL
            let resourcePhoto = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: productPhotoURL)!, cacheKey: productPhotoURL)

            cell.productImageView.kf.setImage(with: resourcePhoto)
        }

        // Customize AddToCart btn
        cell.addToCartBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        cell.addToCartBtn.layer.borderWidth = 2
        cell.addToCartBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        return cell
    }


    // Set URL Google
    extension URLGoogle{
        static let googleAPIUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q="
        static let googleSearchPhotosOnly = "&imgType=photo&imgSize=medium&searchType=image"
        static let googleSearchEngineID = "&cx=004797504301667307438:v974oybby28"
        static let googleAPIKey = "&key=AIzaSyA_QlOnYMZLbFCV_oh49Z97_tx7zA-Qeig"
    }
```

Here is the bug:

[image]

Here is my source code for my project, maybe is helping you more then this sample: https://bitbucket.org/florentin89/shoppingland/src/c0d06b7d5a307ca8ee6f4ab6f962e81f2afbd0d5/ShoppingLand/Controller/ProductsViewController.swift?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default

If you need any more info please don't hesitate to ask me.

Thank you so much for your time if you are reading this !

Comment: Any idea guys ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ChihuahuaExtreme` with content of name `textField`  in `requestURL`

Comment: Im doing that with the variable `query`. I think I'm not doing ok the loop for each product in part (first line of code from my function).

Comment: I can see you are using ChihuahuaExtreme as it is. You are assigning value in query but not using it anywhere.

Comment: the value of `query` is used in the requestURL. I updated my code and I added the function CellForRowAt where I use the indexPath.

Comment: Any idea guys ?